# Personal notes when preparing a talk with LaTeX-beamer class

Tags: beamer, comments, workflow

Suppose I prepare a talk using the `beamer` class. To each slide I want to add personal notes (detailing what I exactly want to say, frequently asked questions etc.). So is there a smart way to write those notes into the same file and get a nice printed version of my slides with my personal comments (of course the presentation itself should be without those notes)?

Comment: also note the question about how to display those best, in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84622/33322 - the answer there being [pdfpc](https://pdfpc.github.io/)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You are interested in the `\note` command. Please refer to Section **19 Adding Notes for Yourself** of the `beamer` [manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

A little example (taken from the manual):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeameroption{show notes} un-comment to see the notes

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> Eggs
  \item<2-> Plants
    \note[item]<2>{Tell joke about plants.}
    \note[item]<2>{Make it short.}
  \item<3-> Animals
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

To print the note pages without hints or fancy settings, you can use the `plain` option for the `note page` template:

```
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]
```

Comment: Also, when you want to present this on an extended screen, I can highly recommend the (Windows/Linux/Mac) software [pympress](https://github.com/Cimbali/pympress) to display this in presenter mode. Other options are listed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux).

Comment: What if your `itemize` environment isn't using overlay specifications?

Comment: Nice! I can print a version without notes, a version with notes. But is it possible to print a version with only the notes?