# PDF preview on other monitor

Tags: pdf, texmaker

Is there any way that allows me to have my PDF preview on a different monitor? I know that you can have Adobe open your PDF automatically instead of the built in previewer, but when I use this I always have to close the PDF before I can recompile.

I work on Windows 7, 64bit and use Texmaker

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) unfortunately your question lacks some information that is needed to answer it. Therefore please edit your question and describe a bit more in detail, how your workflow is and which operating system and TeX editor you use. With your actual question we would be forced to guess what you are doing and any answers would be rather unprecise.

Comment: See [Is there a specialized Pdf viewer for Latex-Beamer presentations on Linux?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84622)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While Adobe Reader has a beautiful rendering, you might prefer a different  PDF viewer for previewing. If you have a PDF viewer in a separate window, that reloads the PDF without closing and reopening, it is easy. You can just drag it to the other monitor once and it will stay there while refreshing. I use [SumatraPDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/), which supports this kind of silent refresh. It also doesn't lock the PDF file and offers the possibility to jump back to the right place in source code by clicking in the PDF (SyncTeX, cf. [forward-inverse-search](/questions/tagged/forward-inverse-search)). I used Texmaker and its forks this way under Windows. You can refresh the pdf manually with <kbd>r</kbd> or let your GUI refresh it via command line as soon as the compilation of the PDF to  review has finished.

Additionally to SumatraPDF as an external PDF viewer, which can be called from any GUI, there is at least one fork of Texmaker that offers a PDF preview window without external tools, with all the possibilities I mentioned above. Maybe it's [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/).

Maybe you have to deal with the focus of SumatraPDF and decide if it should stay at your TeX GUI window or change to the external PDF viewer window.

Comment: The mentionned fork of texmaker that has an integrated previewer with automatic document reload is indeed texstudio. This feature is one of the reasons that made it my favourite TeX editor, as one does not have to fiddle around with weird command line options and stuff but it works just out of the box.

Comment: Won't it work with evince too? Is sumatrapdf really necessary?

Answer (score 19):

With newer versions of Texmaker (>4.5) the built-in viewer can be detached and moved to another screen. Via `Options -> Configure Texmaker` just untick the `Embed` (marked in image) in the "Pdf Viewer" section.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about Texmaker, but on Windows, you can achieve this with SublimeText2 as an editor, associated with its plugin LaTeXTools and SumatraPDF as a viewer.

You can keep the viewer window opened (on any monitor) and it will be updated each time a new compilation succeeds. You will be able to do forward and inverse search.

Comment: Is the editor really relevant?

Comment: The editor is relevant as soon as it brings its own pdf viewer. As the the question asks about "...the built in previewer", it obviously is important what editor the OP uses.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to use SumatraPDF to preview my documents in Texmaker?

Comment: Why Sumatrapdf? Can't one use evince?

Comment: Does this work with sublime text 3?

Comment: Yes it also work with sublime text 3 (and probably lot of other editors), and yes you could use any pdf viewer that can take a page and line from command line