# Overleaf: error compiling in a popup window

Tags: overleaf

I was trying to use a method detailed in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644043) by [Jonas Metzger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/270288/jonas-metzger) on the browser Brave, I have not tried on other browsers. I recieve the following error while clicking the button:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'src')
> at HTMLButtonElement.btn.onclick (:5:55)
> btn.onclick @ VM6313:5

this happens both with an add-on to run the code or me doing it manually. Do you know what is wrong, could somebody help?

P.S. I have a stupid request do you know how to make the button blend with the dark theme?

Comment: this seems to be purely a javacript question so for stackoverflow (or overleaf support) Not sure it is on topic here

Comment: I understand that, but the answer I'm linking to is on this forum so I thought it would be relevant even if tangentially

Comment: someone might answer, but the initial question was "how do I configure this tex editor" which is more or less on topic, it wasn't explicitly asking for javascript debugging,. but if it broke because of a change in the underlying overleaf code, probably overleaf support is your best bet. Alhough they may not want to support random patches to their code:-)

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf support here. I'm afraid that the answer you linked to relies on Overleaf internals that we changed recently, so it can't be used anymore. However, the feature to detach the PDF viewer is available to our beta users, so you can get it by joining our Beta programme via https://www.overleaf.com/beta/participate

Comment: Thanks Tom, that is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @yo' looks like an answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Once we have it out from Beta to everyone, I plan to add an answer to the original question and then this could be marked as a dupe...

Comment: @yo' OK thanks, good plan.