# PDF viewer for LaTeX beamer

Tags: beamer, pdf, viewers, transition

I'm searching a PDF viewer for FreeBSD (Linux) which supports beamer's transition effects (I've some presentation with timed items). Adobe Acrobat Reader drops Unix-support.

I don't need two-monitor, elapsed time, next slide, etc. feature as in ["Is there a specialized Pdf viewer for Latex-Beamer presentations on Linux?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux)'s answers.

Comment: wait, was going to suggest Impressive but then I read "timed items". What do you mean, Are they javascript related stuff?

Comment: Sorry, my english isn't too good. "Timed items": appears a slide with partial content and after 5 seconds appears automagically more part of slide (e.g. items in itemize environment or any other). I hope it's clear now.

Comment: that would be the `\transduration` effect, which should work in most pdf viewer (also in Okular).

Comment: Yes :) But in the lightweight viewers doesn't work (mupdf and similar) this effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Okular, it worked great for me in the past.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In the current form, your answer would be better posted as a comment. Answers here, are expected to provide a good level of details. You can improve yours, for example by stating why (detail the motivations) the OP should try to use Okular. Maybe you can also post an example of Beamer presentation with transitions including a gif file to show whether they are supported.

Comment: Okular does not support the `\transfade` transition, see [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=317073)

Comment: @dcmst and the other transitions are supported? I think I can live without transfade :) /supported transfade would be better of course/

Comment: @uzsolt basically Okular does not support the transitions introduced by the PDF specs v1.5, so: `\transcover`, `\transfade`,`\transpush`,`\transuncover`.