# Problem with pdfpc and latex-beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, pdf, viewers, presentations

I have a figure which uses pattern. The same behavior I notice with one of the examples of pgfplots, http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf page 211.

When I use envince everything looks normal see this image

[image]

But when I want to use pdfpc (see [Is there a specialized Pdf viewer for Latex-Beamer presentations on Linux?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux/84763#84763)) to give a presentation, I get the following figure

[image]

Is this solvable? By either editing the tikz code a bit or by pdfpc? I guess the problem lies with pdfpc which probably uses a different pdf renderer.

I also tried compiling the plot seperatly using the `\documentclass{standalone}` and then embed the figure `.pdf` into the presentation. This leads however to the same result.

The only result which I see if it cannot be fixed by either editing the code or being able to do something with pdfpc is by saving the figure as a `.png` or `.jpg`. I however rather not want to do that. Since I embed most of my tikz figures directly in my presentation such that I can animate them using `\only` and `\onslide`.

However maybe there are some other solutions? Maybe using a different pattern?

I hope someone can help me with this.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[area legend,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
domain=0:1,
legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)},
anchor=north west},
axis on top,xmin=0]
\addplot[pattern=crosshatch dots,
pattern color=blue,draw=blue,
samples=500]
{sqrt(x)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[pattern=crosshatch,
pattern color=blue!30!white,
draw=blue!30!white]
{x^2} \closedcycle;
\addplot[red,line legend] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\legend{$\sqrt x$,$x^2$,$x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

-- Edit --

I believe the problem is with a pdf library which I have installed or the graphics driver. On a different laptop, which has ubuntu 12.04 (I have ubuntu 14.04) there is no problem...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, patterns that were supposed to be clipped. I found that after updating from the stable version in my distribution's repos (pdfpc-3.1.1) to the most current version (4.0.3) this was resolved. I could not find the relevant issue in their bug tracker.