# presentation software with timer for latex beamer presentation on two screens

Tags: beamer, presentations, linux

I'm trying to setup the beamer presentation on two screens usings `pdfpc`.
the main screen (HDMI1 -- obtained from xrandr in Linux) is used for the presentation, while the (DP2, secondary monitor) is used for showing me the slide that is next, remaining time, etc.

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux) reply here shows only a solution for notes.. i also want the timer

Is it possible to do this? Is there some trick in latex to project the next slide on the chosen secondary monitor?

Else, is it possible on `Okular` or `something` to just project the "remaining time" on the secondary monitor?

I'm using Ubuntu and here is the configuration on my beamer:

```
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={Fit}}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
```

Is there a specific way I need to setup my `xrandr` for `pdfpc`

Comment: With which arguments are you calling `pdfpc` now? And what do you see? Have a look at the available options https://pdfpc.github.io/manpage.html

Comment: These are the options I'm using: `pdfpc --duration=20 --last-minutes=2 -S`. It shows me a single slide on a screen without extending the presentation across mutliple monitors.

Comment: Don't use `-S` this is short for `−−single−screen`. How does it look now? (Unfortunately I can't test myself)

Comment: Still does not help. :-(

Comment: Maybe you have a better change to get a useful answer if you ask here: https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc/issues

Comment: I'll shoot a comment there as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as issue with the pdf viewer