# Is it possible to edit the visualisation of the notes using the Présentation tool?

Tags: beamer, presentations, notes, macos

Is it possible to edit the visualisation of the notes using the [Présentation](http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/) tool?

By default, in the notes, it shows the date, the title (twice) and the captions of the figures (if any). I would like to have just the notes in the notes section. How can I do that?

I am using the following options

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
```

Then I use the command `\note` whenever I need a note

```
\note{my notes somewhere}
```

Why is this even happening? Shouldn't it just visualise the notes inside the command `\note{}`?

From the guide, I can only increase and the decrease the font size of the notes.

Comment: Whilst it is very much Tex orientated It is a bit specialist Support site  seems to be currently active however your requirements to edit notes at first glance seem to have been outstanding for some time though there has been recent movement see https://bitbucket.org/rndblnch/osx-presentation/issues/27/enhancing-note-support perhaps worth a query there as to possibilities or wait to see if other TeX SE users can answer

Answer (score 1):

The manual mentions some options for the note page (section 19.1 *Specifying Note Contents* at the end). One of the options is `[plain]`, which inserts only the notes and not the date and the slide preview.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]
\begin{frame}
A frame.
\begin{figure}
A figure.
\caption{A caption.}
\label{fig:ex}
\end{figure}
\note{This is a note shown on the right.}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Note (pun intended): you didn't provide a minimal example so I took the one from the manual, if it does not work in your presentation then you need to provide a complete example yourself that shows the undesired behavior.

Comment: Or some other options mentioned on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux, most are for Linux but some are for Mac as well.

Comment: MacPorts is a port so some problems can be expected - you can try asking a question on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ to solve such issues.