# Dual-screen beamer and zoom conferencing

Tags: beamer, notes

I have made a beamer presentation for my [Zoom conference](https://zoom.us/). Is there a way I can share only the slides and not my notes using zoom platform? I plan to open the slides with the [Dual-Screen PDF viewer](https://github.com/projekter/dspdfviewer/releases/tag/1.15.1.4).

Comment: Could you post an example ? I've never used `beamer` notes

Comment: @BambOo check [this](https://gist.github.com/andrejbauer/ac361549ac2186be0cdb) out

Comment: Frankly this seems to be very viewer specific...

Comment: Did you manage to do what you wanted ?

Comment: Not really. I think its because of how zoom works and how the dpviewer occupies immediately the screens.

Answer (score 1):

When you choose to "share" in a Zoom session, you should be given an option of sharing a single window or sharing an entire screen/desktop.

Use one of the tools specified in existing questions/answers like mine, [How to share a beamer PDF by teleconference (Zoom/etc) using the "show notes on second screen" option?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546729/how-to-share-a-beamer-pdf-by-teleconference-zoom-etc-using-the-show-notes-on?rq=1), or this one, [Is there a specialized Pdf viewer for Latex-Beamer presentations on Linux?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux?rq=1)

These can display the audience material and the presenter material separately, each in windows that can be sized and moved around.  So perfect for zoom.