# Making beamer slides fill the whole screen for video presentations via shared screen

Tags: beamer

I would like to use the beamer package for a presentation, but I wont be using an actual beamer, it will be just be a video call and I will be sharing my screen.
I currently cannot figure out how I can get rid of the black borders around my slides. I tried setting the pdfpagemode to fullscreen and also setting the aspect ratio, but the black borders are still there.
For viewing the pdf I tried Evince, Zathura and Firefox.

Also I have three screens attached, I'm not sure if this might be a problem.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\title[Test]{Test Presentation}
\author[Test Person]{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth, height=.5\textheight]{test.png}}
\institute[Some Uni]{Test Person}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
 {
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}
  }
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

How can I achieve a fullscreen presentation or is it maybe just not possible with beamer?

Comment: Actually within firefox it's working now if I set the aspectratio to 16:9 and then switch to presentation mode.

Comment: Does this question resolved?

Comment: I guess partially at least. I'm still wondering if that's the best option or if beamer even is the right tool to use here.

Comment: It seems the problem can be solved by producing pdf with the same aspect ratio as screen monitor, and then viewing the pdf in fullscreen mode. It doesn't matter if that pdf is produced by latex or any other software, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a concrete answer for you. My two cents: Maybe you should try [`dspdfviewer`](https://dspdfviewer.danny-edel.de/), which is a free and open-source PDF viewer specifically designed for LaTeX beamer presentations. More specifically, for showing the presentation in one screen and the notes on the other. It was quite useful to me.

> "Both screens will be rendered and scaled completely independent of
> each other, so you can use two screens with different resolutions
> and/or aspect ratios, such as your 16:10 laptop screen and a 4:3
> beamer, or the other way around. Please use both devices’ native
> resolutions for maximum image quality."

Another free and open-source possibility is [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/). Finally, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84622/23481) may be useful to you.