# Beameroptions in combination with pdfpc / pdfpages

Tags: beamer, pdfpages

I think I did not understand yet how to use pdfpc in Ubuntu in combination with pdfpages properly.
I would like to use the \notes command to make proper nodes and then, using two screens, I want the current slide on the left side and all the rest like the next page and my notes on the right side.

From a StackOverflow question ([Is there a specialized Pdf viewer for Latex-Beamer presentations on Linux?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux)), I found the following code for beamer:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
```

The problem is that I have no idea what it actually does because the man page is not available on their website anymore.

The result looks like that (both screens together), which appears highly weird to me:
[image]

The right side has the current slide and the notes together and the left side is just highly weird.

Is there anybody who can explain it a bit better how to use that properly?

I use

```
pdfpc Presentation.pdf
```

as my terminal command on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does `pdfpc --notes=right Presentation.pdf` work? I believe that this should match the 'show notes on second screen' used with Beamer.

Comment: Correct. It works, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

@twsh found the answer.
I need to change the terminal command and include --notes=right inside there

The command then becomes that one:

```
pdfpc -w --switch-screens --notes=right Presentation.pdf
```

I also switched screens as they where they wrong way around and -w aims to show both parts in separate windows such that its easier to share it with various programmes like Discord and Zoom