# How do I view the comments inside the pdfnote/note commands in prensenter modes for presentation prepared with beamer

Tags: beamer, compiling, notes, slideshow

```
\documentclass[serif,11pt]{beamer}


%=================================================
% theme and color
%=================================================
\usetheme{Warsaw} %Themes http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

\definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{96, 34, 59}
\definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{140, 151, 154}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=colorA,bg=colorB}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\usepackage[ruled, linesnumbered, vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{epsfig, subfigure, amssymb, multirow, algorithmic, amsmath}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\newcommand*{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\rm #1}}}
\newcommand*{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\rm #1}}}

\newcommand{\pdfnote}[1]{\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{#1}}}%

\newcounter{saveenumi}
\newcommand{\seti}{\setcounter{saveenumi}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand{\conti}{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{saveenumi}}}
\resetcounteronoverlays{saveenumi}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] 
\usepackage[british]{datetime}
%===============
%(preamble)
%==============
\title[State University, South \hspace{0.6cm} \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]
{hidden Markov model for the detection and classification of fishs \vspace*{-0.3cm}}
\author[]{\vspace*{-0.2cm}Cutie Mohammed}
\institute{Department of Electrical and Electronic Engineering, \\ State uni, South}

\begin{document}
    
    %========================
    % title page
    %========================
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{0.02cm}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{kks.jpeg}
        \end{center}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Contents}   
        \tableofcontents 
    \end{frame}
    
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \begin{frame}{Background}
        \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
        \Large {Introduction.}
        \pdfnote{\alert {...because of their importance. The importance include....}}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item  Economic value.
            \pdfnote{\alert {Economics importance of whales are:} \newline Tourism: whale watching and tourism involve about 87 nations 
                \newline generates \$2 Billion annually (J S Smith paper)
                \newline Thus, creating employments \& generate revenue for government.}
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \pause \item Contribute to the maintenance of healthy marine ecosystem.
            \pdfnote{Predator control: They serve as predators, thus controlling the population of small marine animals.
                \item Circulate ocean nutrients when they defecate: because they consume small mammal,  
                \item Reduce the amount of carbon in the ocean because they consume large amount of small fish.
                \item Climate regulation: because they store carbon in their body.
                \item Serve as sentry (guard) species for marine system.}
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \pause \item Security.
            \pdfnote{Because of their exceptional sensory capabilities, whale have been deployed by military organisations for tasks such as mine detection and clearance, port security and coastal patrol.}   
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the `\pdfnote`s to be shown as beamer notes?

Comment: Yes, please. I want to be able to view the notes separately (on my screen when presenting) while the version without notes will be projected to the audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either directly use beamer's `\note` macro or you could redefine the `\pdfnote` macro like this:

```
\documentclass[serif,11pt]{beamer}


%=================================================
% theme and color
%=================================================
\usetheme{Warsaw} %Themes http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

\definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{96, 34, 59}
\definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{140, 151, 154}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=colorA,bg=colorB}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\usepackage[ruled, linesnumbered, vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{epsfig, subfigure, amssymb, multirow, algorithmic, amsmath}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\newcommand*{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\rm #1}}}
\newcommand*{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\rm #1}}}

\newcommand{\pdfnote}[1]{\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{#1}}}%

\newcounter{saveenumi}
\newcommand{\seti}{\setcounter{saveenumi}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand{\conti}{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{saveenumi}}}
\resetcounteronoverlays{saveenumi}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] 
\usepackage[british]{datetime}
%===============
%(preamble)
%==============
\title[State University, South \hspace{0.6cm} \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]
{hidden Markov model for the detection and classification of fishs \vspace*{-0.3cm}}
\author[]{\vspace*{-0.2cm}Cutie Mohammed}
\institute{Department of Electrical and Electronic Engineering, \\ State uni, South}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\renewcommand{\pdfnote}[1]{\note{#1}}


\begin{document}
    
    %========================
    % title page
    %========================
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{0.02cm}
%            \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{kks.jpeg}
        \end{center}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Contents}   
        \tableofcontents 
    \end{frame}
    
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \begin{frame}{Background}
        \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
        \Large {Introduction.}
        \pdfnote{\alert{...because of their importance. The importance include....}}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item  Economic value.
            \pdfnote{\alert {Economics importance of whales are:} \newline Tourism: whale watching and tourism involve about 87 nations 
                \newline generates \$2 Billion annually (J S Smith paper)
                \newline Thus, creating employments \& generate revenue for government.}
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \pause \item Contribute to the maintenance of healthy marine ecosystem.
            \pdfnote{Predator control: They serve as predators, thus controlling the population of small marine animals.
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Circulate ocean nutrients when they defecate: because they consume small mammal,  
                \item Reduce the amount of carbon in the ocean because they consume large amount of small fish.
                \item Climate regulation: because they store carbon in their body.
                \item Serve as sentry (guard) species for marine system.
                \end{itemize}
                }
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \pause \item Security.
            \pdfnote{Because of their exceptional sensory capabilities, whale have been deployed by military organisations for tasks such as mine detection and clearance, port security and coastal patrol.}   
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

(for a list of specialized pdf viewers to show the notes on a separate screen, see [Is there a specialized Pdf viewer for Latex-Beamer presentations on Linux?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux))

Comment: Thank you, but what I want is that one that will only show the notes to the presenter only while the audience will view the main content. I opened this with IpePresenter, the notes showed on both screens. 
Can you help further, please?

In addition, I noticed that the \setbeameroption is highlighted in my texstudio (though the output without error). Could this be a problem?

Comment: @Cutie See the link at the bottom of my answer for a list of viewers which deal well with note pages.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Cutie You're welcome!