# Adding notes to beamer slide when using "\pause"

Tags: beamer, notes, pause

I know how to add personal notes to slides thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48402/personal-notes-when-preparing-a-talk-with-latex-beamer-class)

But, when I use `\pause` inside the frame, it duplicates the note, like in this example:

```
%\documentclass[notes]{beamer}       % print frame + notes
\documentclass[notes=only]{beamer}   % only notes
%\documentclass{beamer}              % only frames

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item talk about sth
    \pause
    \item talk about other thing
\end{itemize}

\note{talk about sth more}

\end{frame}  

\end{document}
```

[image: duplicated notes]

I want it to output only one note for that frame, how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Does the `handout` option for the `beamer` class do what you want?

Comment: nope, it does not work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify that the note should only be shown for the first overlay using `\note<1>{...}`

You should not use the `notes=only` class option, it is obsolete and beamer will tell you this with a warning.

```
\documentclass{beamer}  

\setbeameroption{show only notes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item talk about sth
    \pause
    \item talk about other thing
\end{itemize}

\note<1>{talk about sth more}

\end{frame}  

\end{document}
```