# How to expand beamer's slides vertically according to the length of the content?

Tags: beamer, paper-size, notes

I am looking for some kind of blend between a slide and a standalone document type where I can add as many comments/notes as I want. A slide because I am making slides, and a standalone in that the latter has no page height restrictions, so **(i) I can add as many comments as I want (ii) inside the slide**. Importantly, the length of the slides should be dynamic in the sense that it depends on how much content and comments there are in that particular slide. Thus, **I want a way to dynamically adjust the vertical size of the slides depending on the content of each slide.**

I'm aware it is possible to add notes to beamer with the `\note` command, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48402/personal-notes-when-preparing-a-talk-with-latex-beamer-class). This method **creates new slides** with the extra notes, and thus it is not what I need. I want something different.

Let me give you an example. Assume I have the following two slides to present:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \frametitle{Frame 1}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1 with equation:

        $$ \frac{\alpha}{\beta}=3 $$

        \item Item 2 with qoute:

        \begin{quote}
            \lipsum[101-101]
        \end{quote}

    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

    \frametitle{Frame 2}

    \begin{itemize}

        \item Item 1 with quote:

        \begin{quote}
            \lipsum[108-108]
        \end{quote}

        \item Item 2 with table:    

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
            S & A & T & O & R\\ \hline
            A & R & E & P & O\\ \hline
            T & E & N & E & T\\ \hline
            O & P & E & R & A\\ \hline
            R & O & T & A & S\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}

    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, what I actually want is to use the slide format to store comments that relate to each point in the slide. So, using the `article` document type together with the `beamerarticle` package I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\redcomment}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\bf [ \footnotesize #1 ]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \frametitle{Frame 1}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1 with equation:

        $$ \frac{\alpha}{\beta}=3 $$

        \redcomment{\lipsum[3-3]}

        \item Item 2 with qoute:

        \begin{quote}
            \lipsum[101-101]
        \end{quote}

        \redcomment{\lipsum[6-8]}

    \end{itemize}

    \redcomment{Other comments: \lipsum[5-5]}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

    \frametitle{Frame 2}

    \begin{itemize}

        \item Item 1 with quote:

        \begin{quote}
            \lipsum[108-108]
        \end{quote}

        \item Item 2 with table:    

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
            S & A & T & O & R\\ \hline
            A & R & E & P & O\\ \hline
            T & E & N & E & T\\ \hline
            O & P & E & R & A\\ \hline
            R & O & T & A & S\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}

        \redcomment{\lipsum[29-30]}

    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you compile this, you see I get this:

[image]

This is of course an article type of document, so it doesn't have the slide format, nor has a dynamic page size (and I made the comments on frame 1 long on purpose so it overflows into page 2). I imagine a dynamic page size in the article mode makes no sense at all, so `article` + `beamerarticle` are of no use. The solution probably would have to come by either redefining some functions in the beamer package, or by making standalone compatible with beamer. Both of this go beyond my knowledge. Any ideas?

PS: it would be amazing if the solution also includes a command to turn off the comments, equivalent to the `\setbeameroption{show notes}` command when using notes in beamer.

PS2: you might wonder why I want this. My aim is to have background material for preparing slides, organised already in slide format. An alternative is to have a document accompanying a set of slides, but this is far from efficient in my view. I also think it is easier to organise my thoughts in the presentation mode than in the document mode.

Comment: You can always put the text into a \parbox or minipage using a given height and [s] (stretch).  The main problem is that beamer does not compute the height of the title until after the body has been formatted.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397523/tikz-based-beamer-frame/397557?r=SearchResults&s=2|24.6381#397557

Comment: use of `$$`...bad form... see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to