# Beamer - compile two sets of .pdfs one with and another without notes

Tags: beamer, notes

Is it possible to simultaneously prepare two sets of Beamer slides - one with and another without notes?

Kind regards,
Syed

Comment: Does this answer address your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48402/personal-notes-when-preparing-a-talk-with-latex-beamer-class

Comment: @twsh: no. I am preparing lecture slides (for me, with notes using \note command) that I will modify frequently and share with students (without notes version). Ideally, I would like to generate two sets of pdfs simultaneously (with and without notes) rather than switching between options -"show notes" and "hide notes".

Comment: Perhaps you could try this. Have one main file 'content.tex' and two 'wrappers' with different preambles. Each wrapper then has `\input{content.tex}`. You can then make PDFs from both wrappers. You could even automate that by using, e.g., make and have one command for each one.

Comment: Great idea; i will try as suggested.

Comment: You can use the techniques shown at https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583