# Make beamer accessible (visual impairment)?

Tags: beamer, accessibility

I wanted to know if it is possible to include "Speaker notes" in the beamer slides. I want to make a presentation accessible and use the speaker notes to also add detailed descriptions of the figures, tables and so on.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please add the tag "accessibility" for wider visibility by readers of this forum.  (I would do that, but a technical glitch prevents it.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Personal notes when preparing a talk with LaTeX-beamer class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48402/personal-notes-when-preparing-a-talk-with-latex-beamer-class)